# How to group together tables of similar name and values associated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following script in SQL Server 2008:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    table_name sysname ,
    row_count INT,
    reserved_size VARCHAR(50),
    data_size VARCHAR(50),
    index_size VARCHAR(50),
    unused_size VARCHAR(50)
)

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT #temp
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'sp_spaceused ''?'''

SELECT 
   a.table_name,
   a.row_count,
   COUNT(*) AS col_count,
   a.data_size
FROM 
   #temp a
INNER JOIN 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b ON a.table_name COLLATE database_default
= b.table_name COLLATE database_default
GROUP BY 
   a.table_name, a.row_count, a.data_size
ORDER BY 
   CAST(REPLACE(a.data_size, ' KB', '') AS integer) DESC

DROP TABLE #temp
```

The above script outputs all the names of the tables in the database, along with their size in kbs. What I would like to do is group the tables by their name (there are 5 groups: _Result (example approximately 1000 tables such as _Result14, _Result512, _Result999, etc), _Preview, _Adjusted, _History and one group that doesn't fit into the other four). Along with grouping the table names I would like to sum the kb size values so that it displays something like this:

```
Table Type     Size (MB)
------------------------
Preview        35075
Adjusted       24354
Result         7679
Transactional  1163
History        838
```

Any help you could provide would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an aggregation:

```
select (case when table_name like 'Preview%' then 'Preview'
             when table_name like 'Adjusted%' then 'Adjusted'
             when table_name like 'Result%' then 'Result'
             when table_name like 'Transactional%' then 'Transactional'
             when table_name like 'History%' then 'History'
             else 'Other'
        end) as TableType,
       sum(data_size) as TotalSize
from #temp
group by (case when table_name like 'Preview%' then 'Preview'
               when table_name like 'Adjusted%' then 'Adjusted'
               when table_name like 'Result%' then 'Result'
               when table_name like 'Transactional%' then 'Transactional'
               when table_name like 'History%' then 'History'
               else 'Other'
          end);
```

The logic for the `case` may not be exactly right, but it should be close to what you need.

If you want the size in Mbytes rather than kbytes, then divide by 1000.

Comment: Thankyou! Code works great! I wanted to use a different database with the above table groups, as well as Peroid and Trace. However when I add Peroid and Trace to the conditions (when statements) it does not appear in the output. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want:

```
SELECT 
   a.table_name,
   sum(a.data_size)
FROM 
   #temp a
INNER JOIN 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b ON a.table_name COLLATE database_default
= b.table_name COLLATE database_default
GROUP BY 
   a.table_name
```

Comment: so replace this with everything that comes after my select?

Comment: when I run that, it states "operand data type varchar invalid for sum operator

Comment: I used the code below, but this works as well, thankyou!